# saving twitter4J Status to MongoDB gives "twitter4j.Status is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces"

Tags: java, mongodb, jaxb, twitter4j, morphia

Trying to save a `List<Status>` to MongoDB (via Morphia), and I get this compile time error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
twitter4j.Status is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at twitter4j.Status
        at public java.util.List Model.TwitterJob.getStatuses()
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little complicated to marshal `Status`, because the class `StatusJSONImpl` which implements `Status` in Twitter4j 3.0 is protected.
You need to override the class and make it visible to your classes.

Please checkout the following example for detail.

https://github.com/phstudy/Twitter4j_JAXB_example

Comment: I finally implemented a poor man' solution: mapping (almost) all fields from Status to a new Class, that I can then save to Mongo. Your solution is definitely more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify an implementing class of the `Status` interface.

```
@XmlElement(type=SomeStatusImpl.class)
public List<Status> getStatuses() {
    return statuses;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Would be really useful. I can't find any class implementing it though! (http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html). It's either me misreading the Javadoc, or that's the strange way it has been designed. Any thoughts?

Comment: @seinecle - When you have a populated model what is the impl class of `Status`?

Comment: err... I am not sure (not a pro, sorry!). The doc just shows the interface being used, as in: 'Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Status status = twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus);
    System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");'